# Pass text as argument to external program using emacs

Tags: emacs

Let's say I have this text in a file:

```
/home is where the heart is.
```

If for example, I select the `/home` text, using C-spc, is there a way of sending it to ls, so that in the end if will execute `ls /home`? `M-|` does not work.

Comment: +1 for the "I can do everything in Emacs" attitude! :-)

Comment: `M-|` is `shell-command-on-region` which pipes the current region into a command. That won't work. Victor's solution should solve your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to do that in Emacs directly. But everyting is possible with help of elisp:

```
(defun region-as-argument-to-command (cmd)
  (interactive "sCommand: ")
  (shell-command
   (format
    "%s %s"
    cmd
    (shell-quote-argument
     (buffer-substring (region-beginning)
                       (region-end))))))
```

Comment: You probably also want to apply `shell-quote-argument` to the second and third arguments to `format`, or else be careful never to call this function when the region text includes `;rm -rf /`.

Answer (score 5):

Try 
<kbd>M-|</kbd> `xargs ls`.  That is, pass "`xargs ls`" as the shell command on the region selected.

See [xargs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs).

Answer (score 3):

Victor's answer is a good one for the question you asked, but in your specific case you might consider using `M-x ffap` (find-file-at-point). This will give you a `dired` buffer for the `/home` directory.